# Derive total wall area from floor area using only floor area & room height. How?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I work in construction as an estimator. We received scaled architectural drawings, then use a piece of software called Bluebeam to line up the ceilings, walls, floors, etc.

Currently, in order to get the wall areas in a corridor, I have to lineup all of the walls in the corridor using the following formula:

`WALL AREA = (NORTH x HEIGHT) + (EAST x HEIGHT) + (SOUTH x HEIGHT) + (WEST x HEIGHT)`

Then, I proceed to lineup the floors with the following formula:

`FLOOR AREA = (LEGTH x WIDTH)`

**But what if...**

...the total wall area for this corridor could be derived using only the floor area and room height?

I could do an entire apartment complex in half the time or less.

Below is the link to the working google sheets. It contains 2 draft formulas.

[Google Sheets - f2w Calculator](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s_bRnfWr-0Yy_d_V4wmauIs87Bog5MYOR-lKgHKm9cs/edit?usp=sharing)

Just change the wall length of the blue wall to compared the formula results.

**How can I combine the second formula into a single cell?**

Comment: So if you calculated the perimeter? If we assume North is the length of the North wall and East etc then sum(North,South,East,West) ie the total length of all walls. Also, you tagged Excel but say Googlesheets - you need to decide as they can be different in crucial ways.

Comment: If you only have floor area and wall height there is no accurate way to get the correct wall surface.  You would need to assume dimensions. A 3 foot wide hall way on 36 sqft would have 30 lineal feet of perimeter.  But 6 foot wide on the same 36 would be 24. You can always assume a square but that would get you the lowest perimeter. If you want accuracy you will need to know the perimeter.

Comment: Seems to be no more than a 2% margin of error at any scale. Check out `Sheet2`. Edit the blues.

Comment: Actually... it grows. Sigh..!

Comment: Yes the more irregular the shape the greater the difference from the square.

Answer (score 0):

Room Dimensions = **10'L** X **10'W** X **12'H**

1. This formula **only works** for rooms in which **ALL 4 walls are the
   same length**. If the room has more than 4 walls, change `4` for desired number.

Total Wall Area **from** Floor Area = `(4 * SQRT(FLOOR_AREA)) * HEIGHT`

There is no accurate way to derive total wall area from floor area using only floor area & room height because the SQRT function normalizes the length of each wall creating an ever increasing deviation from correct total wall area.

2. This formula **works for ANY** room with 4 walls but **REQUIRES knowledge of
   Perimeter ahead of time.**

Total Wall Area **from** Perimeter = `((2 * LENGTH) + (2 * WIDTH)) * HEIGHT`

Hopefully this saves someone who's persistent from wasting time on this. Thank for all the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite certain of what you're asking, but as a construction estimator myself that uses bluebeam, why not just measure the area in bluebeam and let it do the calculations for you?

[image: Takeoff]

Just trace around the room/area with the area tool at the top, add the wall height to the depth column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I use bluebeam as well. Nothing compares. I just thought that formula could go somewhere.